# Remove Comma from long Type in Jasper Dynamic Report

Tags: eclipse, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am generating dynamic report using jasper API. My environment setup is:-

- Eclipse 3.4
- JSF 1.2
- Rich Faces 3.3
- Jasper Dynamic Reports API 3.1.4
- Java 1.6

a code snippet is as follows:-

```
TextColumnBuilder  employeeNoCol    = col.column("ID.", "empNo", type.longType()).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

What i get for this is :-

```
      OUTPUT                      INTENDED OUTPUT
 ----------------                 --------------
  ID ...                          ID...
 ----------------                 --------------
 12,347                            12347
 33,184                            33184
 10,134,98                         1013498
   .                               .
   .                               .
   .                               .
 ----------------                 ----------------
```

How do i remove this currency format from long type.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably including the thousand separator by default. Try setting another pattern with no thousand separator.

```
TextColumnBuilder  employeeNoCol    = col.column("ID.", "empNo", type.longType()).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).setPattern("########0");
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you change the type long to string and then use

```
TextColumnBuilder  employeeNoCol    = col.column("ID.", "empNo", 
type.stringType()).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
```

Or directly use as below

```
TextColumnBuilder  employeeNoCol    = col.column("ID.", "empNo",
type.longType()).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
.setPattern("#");
```